# JS: Hovered images don't load smoothly

Tags: javascript, image, hover, load

I'm using JS to change pictures on hover... but the hovered pictures don't load smoothly. Any help is appreciated.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('.img-grey').on({
            mouseenter: function (e) {
              var greysrc = $(this).attr('src');
              var colorsrc = greysrc.replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg")
              $(this).attr('src', colorsrc);
            },
            mouseleave: function (e) {
              var colorsrc = $(this).attr('src');
              var greysrc = colorsrc.replace("2.jpg", "1.jpg")
              $(this).attr('src', greysrc);
            }
          })
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try looking for how to preload images in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this task can be solved with css. Check the css attribute selectors https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

All you need is to create next html structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="1path-to-1.jpg" />
    <img src="1path-to-2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="2path-to-1.jpg" />
    <img src="2path-to-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

See attached snippet

```css
.container [src$="2.jpg"] {
 display: none;
}

.container:hover [src$="1.jpg"] {
 display: none;
}

.container:hover [src$="2.jpg"] {
 display: inline;
}

.container {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8aecf6164a04433529bd7702f1b5f59a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&1.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20fc11c3f294bdebe4351e7ca240678?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&2.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b8367b2f25ceee4d54595495b4e51312?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&1.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20fc11c3f294bdebe4351e7ca240678?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&2.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f20fc11c3f294bdebe4351e7ca240678?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&1.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8aecf6164a04433529bd7702f1b5f59a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1&2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but I have a lot of pictures ... it is hard to do it individually in css .. so I make the js that allows me to change between the pictures by changing the last number from 2 to 1 .. I want the pictures 2 and 1 to load together so when it is online it wont need time to load when you move the mouse ..

Comment: That also can be solved with css, see updated answer

Comment: thank you again but I don't see how can I use it for more than one picture can you provide me with example .. please

Comment: thank you .. it is a nice way to do it .. but I will change a lot in my code

Comment: not solved .. when I use it the pictures goes out of their places

Comment: I re-read you question and as I understand you need to colorize image on hover. Am I right?

Comment: yes .. but I already did that.. the problem the pictures not loaded from the beginning.. so when I hover it it needs time to change to the other picture cuz it is not loaded yet ,, so what I need is how can I load all of them from the start of the website loading

Comment: Actually css has ability to apply black&white filters to images, so you don't need to store grey picture at all. Look into this css rule `img.desaturate {
        filter: grayscale(100%);}`

Comment: okay .. how can I use it in more than one picture as hover .. and keeping the position of the column..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preload your images you should put them into DOM or add as background properties. Here's modified version of your code that adds hidden `<img />` elements next to existing. I haven't run it, but it should works

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.img-grey').map(function () {
      var temp = document.createElement('img');
      temp.src = this.src.replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg");
      temp.style.display = 'none';
      $(this).parent().append(temp);
      return this;
    }).on({
      mouseenter: function (e) {
        var greysrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var colorsrc = greysrc.replace("1.jpg", "2.jpg")
        $(this).attr('src', colorsrc);
      },
      mouseleave: function (e) {
        var colorsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var greysrc = colorsrc.replace("2.jpg", "1.jpg")
        $(this).attr('src', greysrc);
      }
    })
});
```